# Link QTableWidget cells to webpages

Tags: python, qt, hyperlink, pyqt, pyside

I was wondering if it is possible to double click on a cell in a `QTableWidget` (I've already disabled cell editing) and it opening a link in a web browser. I'm using PyQt4 for Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
self.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.OpenLink)

def OpenLink(self,item):
    if item.column() == 1:
        webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
```

This is how I solved it in my program, item.text() is the text in the cell, item.row() is it's row number and item.column() the column number.

Comment: Seems like you followed my answer. Therefore if you like, give it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible. You just need to combine two things.

Connect a suitable slot to signal [cellDoubleClicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellDoubleClicked) of `QTableWidget`.

Tell a browser to display a link using the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/webbrowser.html) module of Python.

Comment: Okay so I know how to use the webbrowser module but I get the error ' TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ' when trying to make a cell able to open a link when double clicked.

Comment: @SaiyanElite Why not adding a minimal example showing that error to the question? With only the error message it's difficult to say even if the error message indicates that the problem is rather a simple typo somewhere.